# Google Cloud Storage Transfer Sink Prefix

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've scanned the Storage Transfer docs, but I'm not seeing an example of this scenario. For reference, I'm using this script - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/transfer_service/nearline_request.py

Is there a way to set a prefix for files being transferred from the source bucket to the sink bucket?

For example, if I have this file in the source bucket:
`gs://source_bucket/myFile.csv`
I want to add a prefix to it so that it looks like this in the sink bucket:
`gs://sink_bucket/date/type/myFile.csv`

As far as I can tell, the sink bucket argument only accepts a bucket's name. I'm not seeing an option for something like this in the `transferSpec` docs either. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that as stated on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/transfer-differences) the Storage Transfer Service does not support
destination object prefixes.The main reason behind it being that it currently [does not support  remapping](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-console#select).

My recommendation would be to first use the Storage Transfer service to copy everything from one bucket to another and only afterwards use [any of the available methods to rename the object](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/renaming-copying-moving-objects#rename) in the new bucket to `/date/type/myFile.csv`. As for Cloud Storage [objects don't reside within subdirectories](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/naming-objects#object-considerations) and they merely exist with the name `/date/type/myFile.csv`.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. Like you said, I'll have to add a prefix once I've transferred everything over.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad that the information provided above proved to be useful!